# How to get the post's parent ID?

Tags: posts, blog, id

I have a template which outputs the blog posts (Blog Page), I open one of the posts which use single.php template, Now how can I get the ID of it's parent which is the (Blog Page)?

I should say that I want to use this ID to get the meta box value of the blog page in single.php.

The same goes for a custom post type, let's say 'project', Where a page template list the project's posts (Projects Page) and single-project.php for the single project post.
in this case I want to get the (Projects Page) ID in single-project.php.

Comment: Can you explain the situation, Why do you want to get it?

Comment: Post's parent id is not a blog page, but another post. There is no relation between post and your blog page,

Comment: @VinodDalvi I edited the queston.

Comment: @RajeevVyas so you're saying there is no way to get the ID of blog page?

Comment: @metalzade offcourse not, try using get_option('page_for_posts') or see the is_home function from codex for reference.

Comment: +1 for updating your question with more info. I'm still not sure what you mean. If you have a custom post type, and it is set to 'hierarchical' then you can use `get_post( $post->post_parent )`. If you are using a 'page' for blog posts in the settings, then `get_option('page_for_posts')` will give you the ID. More info and maybe a code snippet will help us give a better answer.

Comment: @MereDevelopment Thanx guys, get_option('page_for_posts') did the trick for the blog page, But for custom post type $post->post_parent is returning 0 which is not right. I did edit the question again.

Comment: You're conflating separate concepts. The parent of a hierarchical custom post type is not the same thing as the page that posts happen to be displayed on.

Comment: @anu OK, I get it now, But do you think there's a way to get that page ID in single-project.php?

Comment: @metalzade there is no relationship unless you define it explicitly. For example, if you had 2 pages that listed the same posts, which should be the 'parent'? So, you can either hardcode it, define it in configuration, or make some implicit assumption (eg by searching for the page that uses the particular template)

Comment: Ain't you looking for [breadcrumbs](https://managewp.com/breadcrumbs-wordpress-seo-by-yoast)?

Answer (score 5):

WordPress 5.7 introduces a new helper function to more easily fetch the parent post's ID:
`get_post_parent()`

This can also be used in conjunction with `has_post_parent()`, so you could have something like looks like:

```
<?php if ( has_post_parent() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink( get_post_parent() ); ?>">
        <?php
        echo sprintf(
            esc_html__( 'Back to parent page: %s', 'text-domain' ),
            get_the_title( get_post_parent() )
        );
        ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note that these functions accept a "child post ID" as a parameter, which defaults to the current post.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/02/10/introducing-new-post-parent-related-functions-in-wordpress-5-7/

Comment: "These functions were originally introduced as get_parent_post() and has_parent_post() but have since been renamed to get_post_parent() and has_post_parent()"

Answer (score 1):

Use `$post->post_parent` to get the parent ID of the post. Here `$post` is an object with properties.

Comment: I was able to get the ID of the blog page by get_option('page_for_posts') but no success in custom post type as $post->post_parent returns 0.

Comment: $post->post_parent is working for me. print your $post object,then you will there is [post_parent] is there.

Comment: You might want to add `global $post`